# Multiple values in a column

Tags: database-design, rdbms

I need some advice regarding multiple records. I have a table with fields `username`,`message` and `message_to`. The scenario could be sending the same message to multiple users in one go. What do you suggest? Will it be efficient to save all recipients in a single column with comma separated values or I add multiple entries?

Answer (score 10):

No, no, no, no, no.

This would be a capital violation of the relational database model. Create three tables: Users, Messages, and MessagesSentToUsers.

- In the `Users` table, store a `user_id` value, and the user's `name`.
- In the `Messages` table, store a `message_id` value and the message `text`.
- In the `MessagesSentToUsers` table create on record for each time a message is sent.  This record should contain only the `user_id` for the user who got the message, and a `message_id` pointing to the message text they received.

Like the following:

```
|       User     |  |      Message      |  |  MessageSentToUsers   |
|---------|------|  |------------|------|  |----------|------------|
| user_id | name |  | message_id | text |  | user_id  | message_id |
```

In general, the id columns in each table will be of type integer.  The most common case is to have the DBMS assign a value to each row (so you don't have to manage the numbers).

Comment: Agreed; sometimes denormalisation is appropriate. But this is not such a time.

Comment: @silky: why? If you need to know "What messages did UserX receive?", this is reasonable. Since Adnan calls the recipients "users", they might already have their own table. If so, @Larry's solution only adds one simple table.

Comment: @Adnan: the negative effect on performance that JOIN will bring and that you seem to fear so much pales in comparison to the goodness of a nicely and properly designed database system. A tiny little bit of performance isn't worth tossing out the most fundamental database design principles. Don't overoptimize ahead of time!

Comment: @marc_s: you're right. Later on I can apply caching techniques once it starts getting out of control. Thanks